# Testing app with RSPEC and Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am generating the test of my app rails with RSPEC, in the application implement searches with elasticsearch with the gem Tire.

Running the tests gives me the following error

```
   Caused by: ---  
 #   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:  
 #   Couldn't find all Artists with 'id': (1, 2, 3) (found 0 results, but was looking for 3)  
 #   /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@tatto/gems/tire-0.6.2/lib/tire/results/collection.rb:157:in `__find_records_by_ids'
```

How can i run elasticsearch in the test environment?